# Coinbase to Coinbase off-chain transaction fees?

Tags: coinbase.com

When I click on "Send" from my bitcoin address which I know is off-chain in Coinbase to another Coinbase address which I also know is off-chain. So technically the transaction will not touch the blockchain, just update their off-chain books locally.

I know it's off-chain, because I deposited money using my credit card, and I scanned all addresses under Tools > Addresses on a blockchain explorer for a few days and there's nothing in there. They're keeping it off-chain until I actually want to spend it. Granted, but if I spend it to another Coinbase off-chain address, they should be able to find out that this is an address they own and they don't need to utilize the blockchain at all and could do it all off-chain as they own both addresses.

If that's the case, why is coinbase still charging me network fees? Sounds like mickey mouse fees to me for updating a record in their database without touching the blockchain.

Are they assuming that I don't know it's a fully off-chain transaction, and think they can charge me regardless? Or does their wizard have a glitch ?

Comment: How do you know if is off-chain? If you are sending to a bitcoin address and a transaction is generated, it is necessarily on-chain.

Comment: Relevant? https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/971437-how-do-i-send-digital-currency-to-another-wallet-

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I know it's off-chain, because I deposited money using my credit card, and I scanned all addresses under Tools > Addresses on a blockchain explorer for a few days and there's nothing in there. They're keeping it off-chain until I actually want to spend it. Granted, but if I spend it to another Coinbase off-chain address, they should be able to find out it doesn't need to utilize the blockchain at all and can do it all off-chain as it owns both addresses. I updated my question.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Not fully, this applies to Coinbase to "any wallet". But for Coinbase to Coinbase transactions and knowing that Coinbase has an off-chain ledger system (they mention it themselves), that should give improved possibilities for Coinbase to Coinbase transactions.

Comment: [Does Coinbase pay miner or network fees when sending digital currency?](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/815435-does-coinbase-pay-bitcoin-miner-fees-) it is stated clearly here "Any transactions sent between Coinbase customers by email address take place off-chain (not on the blockchain) at no cost". Maybe Coinbase have a system that charges network fee as long as "addresses" are used.

Comment: @Chak You might be on to something, indeed when sending funds there's one to send by "Bitcoin address" and another one to send by "Email". I've never tried sending using the Email option, so perhaps when sending by email that might be the channel where it detects that the person has a Coinbase account. Thanks!

Comment: @Chak now that you've solved the question, please post an answer and accept it so the question doesn't remain unanswered :)

Answer (score 2):

[Does Coinbase pay miner or network fees when sending digital currency?](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/815435-does-coinbase-pay-bitcoin-miner-fees-) is stated clearly here "Any transactions sent between Coinbase customers by email address take place off-chain (not on the blockchain) at no cost".
 Maybe Coinbase have a system that charges network fee as long as "addresses" are used.